# How to alter the default value set to a column in a table in SQL?

Tags: sql, default, default-value, alter

How can you alter the default value set to a column in a table in SQL.

I got an error from:

```
ALTER TABLE  tablename.tab ALTER COLUMN mess1 DEFAULT ('hi')
```

What was the correct query?

Answer (score 4):

I would name your constraints. To change an existing one...

```
ALTER TABLE tablename.tab
        DROP CONSTRAINT ....  --you have a system generated name. Well done.
ALTER TABLE tablename.tab
        ADD CONSTRAINT DF_tablename_mess1 DEFAULT 'hi' FOR mess1
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the syntax is a variant of:

```
ALTER TABLE jankhana.jankh MODIFY (mess1 CHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'hi');
```

Technically, the parentheses around the column specification are optional when there's just one column; if there are several, they are mandatory.

The details could vary by DBMS - DDL statements tend to be the most variable.